# std::min is not returning the smaller of two values

Tags: c++

I have this line of code:

```
out = std::min(x - 1, y - 1);
```

But it is returning the **larger** of the two quantities. How can this be?

Comment: Oh really ... and what are `x`, `y`, and `out` values ?

Comment: So what are the quantities?

Comment: @YogiBear: -1. I've answered this for you this time. SO is not a quiz site.

Comment: This question is crying out for an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the OP having a lapse in problem solving skills.

Comment: YogiBear has asked some good questions though.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This can only happen if `x` and `y` are unsigned types and one of them is zero.

Subtracting 1 from an unsigned value 0 will cause an unsigned value to wrap around to the largest possible value for that type. Hence the other value will be smaller.

As a side note: only blame your compiler / STL as a very last resort.

Comment: Thought of that in the first place but you beat me on time. +1

Comment: OP is either in a total panic, in an interview, or both!

Comment: Total panic in an interview sounds correct :)

Comment: This can happen in other cases as well. E.g. both types are `int` and one of the values is `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`

Comment: And much more sinister in that case as I believe the behaviour in that case would be undefined. (Wrap around on unsigned types *is* defined).